# Optimizing a SQL join statement

Tags: sql, inner-join, where-clause

I am joining two tables.  The first contains work orders and their associated part numbers.  The second contains the BOM for all of the part numbers.  They are both large tables.  Individually, I can query the two tables in seconds if not less.  When I perform the join, it takes minutes.  Is it possible that the where at the end of this statement is being performed after the join?  If the join is performed first, I could see this taking a long time.  But if the first table is reduced first by the where, I would think this should go fast.  Is there someway to write a more optimized query?

```
SELECT  Table2.ItemNum As ItemNum  
FROM Table1  
INNER Join Table2  
ON Table1.PartNum = Table2.PartNum
WHERE Table1.WorkOrder = 10100314
```

Comment: Have you indexed your foreign key columns? What does the execution plan look like? What RDBMS is this for?

Comment: Do you have an index on `Table1.WorkOrder`? On the `PartNum` fields?

Comment: what you need is to index your tables.

What database engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That will do a better job:

```
SELECT  Table2.ItemNum As ItemNum  
FROM Table2  
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Table1.WorkOrder = 10100314
)AS Table1
ON Table1.PartNum = Table2.PartNum
```

### Indexes on PartNum fields are required too ...

Comment: Thanks, it helped a bit, but still slow.  I'll have to see if they are indexed or if there is an indexed field that I should be using.

Comment: Used a different field and amazing speed. Thanks

Comment: @Ken @mcolson1590: I am not aware of the difference between the two answers here ..

Comment: You apparently are a little faster typist. :) Deleting my answer, as yours was first.